# get handle to opened chrome window in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

does someone has any scipt in selenium c#,
that instead of this line: 
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

initialize the driver without opening a new chrome window,
i mean, in the second run ,i'll get handle to the chrome that i opened in the previeus run of selenium.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I use.  Chrome allows you to supply your own user-defined command-line arguments.  So you can add an argument named "scriptpid-" with the PID (Windows Process ID) of your currently running program.  ChromeDriver passes your argument to Chrome in the command-line.  Then using Windows WMI calls retrieve this PID from the command-line of the running Chrome ...

```
using System.Management;

public static IntPtr CurrentBrowserHwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
public static int CurrentBrowserPID = -1;
        
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("scriptpid-" + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Get the PID and HWND details for a chrome browser

System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
for (int p = 0; p < processes.Length; p++)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher commandLineSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processes[p].Id);
    String commandLine = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject commandLineObject in commandLineSearcher.Get())
    {
        commandLine += (String)commandLineObject["CommandLine"];
    }

    String script_pid_str = (new Regex("--scriptpid-(.+?) ")).Match(commandLine).Groups[1].Value;

    if (!script_pid_str.Equals("") && Convert.ToInt32(script_pid_str).Equals(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id))
    {
        CurrentBrowserPID = processes[p].Id;
        CurrentBrowserHwnd = processes[p].MainWindowHandle;
        break;
    }
}
```

**CurrentBrowserHwnd** should contain the HWND of your Chrome window.

**CurrentBrowserPID** should contain the Process ID of your Chrome window.

Comment: Thanks @Tal I've updated the answer with "using System.Management;"

Comment: thank you for the fix, but ManagementObjectSearcher stiil not found..

Answer (score 0):

You can call `x.Driver` to get the same instance of the driver.

```
    private static IWebDriver driver;
    public IWebDriver Driver {
        get {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            return driver;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not help me, becouse, if i stop the run, i lose the reference of driver. and in the run after; alwas driver will be null.